# Allocator and STL containers

Tags: c++, stl, containers, allocator

I'm trying to reproduce the std::vector container, and I saw that in one of the vector constructor prototype we can give an allocator.

```
explicit vector (size_type n, const value_type& val = value_type(),const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

So two questions came to my mind
first,  why are we able to give an allocator knowing that we already have the allocator_type member type ?
second, what happen if I give a different allocator to the constructor ?

So I've tried this code.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::allocator<bool> alloc;

    std::vector< std::string > ve(10, "hello", alloc);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        std::cout << ve[i] << " | ";
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Giving a bool allocator to construct a std::string vector works fine and valgrind doesn't complain about it.

So I'm wondering if the bool allocator gived to the constructor is really used, and if he's not what's the point to be able to give an allocator that can be different from the allocator_type to the constructor ?

Thanks for reading me.

Comment: (1) The allocator is defaulted in the [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) template.  (2) The passed allocator is copied and used by the container.

Comment: The `allocator_type` member is set to whatever is specified in the `Allocator` template argument. This is the *type* of the allocator.  The constructor accepts an *instance* of that type. If you don't provide an instance, the `vector` will create one internally by default. So, `std::vector<std::string>` expects a `std::allocator<std::string>`, don't give it a `std::allocator<bool>`. I would not expect this code to compile, but it does, I do not know why. Feel free to step into the code with a debugger and find out why for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I dont really know any debugging things except valgrind could you give me a reference tutorial or documentation for debugging things like this please thanks.

Comment: _"...The behavior is undefined (until C++20)The program is ill-formed (since C++20) if Allocator::value_type is not the same as T...."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: @RichardCritten This does not apply to the shown code though, where the two _do_ match.

Comment: @user17732522  I thought for `std::allocator<bool>`, `Allocator::value_type` would be `bool` and for `std::vector< std::string >` `T` would be `std::string` which don't match.

Comment: @RichardCritten `std::vector<std::string>`'s `Allocator` template argument is defaulted to `std::allocator<std::string>`, no matter how the constructor is called and the parameter of the constructor is the same `Allocator`, not some template parameter of the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why are we able to give an allocator knowing that we already have the allocator_type member type ?

Same reason any type is different from an instance of that type: state.

It is possible to write stateful allocators, where the specific allocator object passed to a particular container affects how it works (for example, which memory pool it allocates from).

> what happen if I give a different allocator to the constructor ?

For your particular case, even before C++20, [`std::allocator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocator) has a non-explicit converting constructor which will  construct the correct `std::allocator<std::string>` from the argument you passed.

Obviously this only works when the `allocator` type parameter is either `std::allocator`, or some user-defined allocator with a similar converting constructor.

---

For clarity, there is also a rebind mechanism specifically to help with changing an `allocator<T>` parameter to a related `allocator<U>`.

This is needed for node-based containers like

```
std::map<Key, Value, Compare, Allocator=std:allocator<std::pair<const Key, Value>>>
```

because the map doesn't really allocate `pair<const Key,Value>`, but some private internal  type like `map<Key,Value>::__node_impl`. Obviously the client can't be expected to pass an allocator of the correct type, because it doesn't *know* the correct type.

Before C++17 this was a member template, and now it uses [`std::allocator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits) instead. It doesn't participate at all in your example code, though, because the allocator constructor argument still needs to be the same type as the type parameter, even if that isn't the type eventually used.

Answer (score 2):

The code that you have posted will work with some standard library implementations, and fail to compile with others.

Libstdc++, for example, will take the allocator you pass, and immediately create a new allocator (of the correct type) using `rebind`.

Libc++, on the other hand, will reject the code with a `static_assert` message.

Comment: There will be an implicit conversion on the constructor argument regardless. The constructor is not templated on the allocator type.

Answer (score 1):

The `allocator_type` member (which is equal to the corresponding template parameter of the `std::vector` class template) determines the type of the allocator used by the vector. Its `value_type` member must be equal to the `value_type` of the vector, otherwise there is no guarantee that the vector will work correctly. But in your example `allocator_type` is `std::allocator<std::string>` (from the default template argument), matching the `value_type` which is `std::string`.

But that determines only the *type* of the allocator, not its value. An allocator is allowed to have state, so you can't always use it just knowing its type. (Although that is sufficient in the case of `std::allocator`, which is stateless.)

The parameter to the constructor takes the value for the allocator to use by the vector (and is defaulted to be default-constructed). It is of the exact same type `allocator_type`. It is not a different type. If you pass it a different type, then either it will fail to compile or it will implicitly convert to `allocator_type`. Any specialization of `std::allocator` can be implicitly converted to any other, which is why it doesn't matter what specialization of `std::allocator` you pass to the constructor. (For allocators other than `std::allocator` the conversion only needs to be possible explicitly, not necessarily implicitly.) The constructor is not templated on the allocator type. It has a parameter of type `allocator_type` exactly.